# React useState does not take correct state from child component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, components, state, parent-child

```
export default Parent = () => { 
    const [str, setStr] = useState<string>("test");

    useEffect(() => {
       setStr(val); // this line seems does not matter
       console.log(str); // correct input from child
    }, [str]);

    const functionA = (name) => {
        console.log(name); // correct value from child
        setStr(name);
        console.log(str); // prints "test" first then the correct valuefrom the child 
    };

    console.log(val2); // correct value from child

    const functionB = () => {
        const text = str;
        console.log(text); // prints "test" first then the correct valuefrom the child
    };

    
    return (
       <child featureA={functionA} featureB={featureB}/>}
    );
}





interface childProps {
    featureA: (name) => void;
    featureB: () => void;
}
    
export default Child = (props: childProps) => {
    const [input, setInput] = useState<string>("");

    const onClickHandler = () => {
        featureA(input); // input is from user type in a text area
        featureB();
    }
}
```

Basically the parent component passes two callback functions (`functionA` and `functionB`) to the child component to get some status and inputs from the child, and prints out these inputs (for simplicity, only one input is shown above).

The printout of each `console.log` is in the comment next to it.

I only want `console.log(text)` to print out the correct value from the child (such as `console.log(str)`), but would not able to do it. In `functionA`, the correct value is passed in (`console.log(name)`), but the `setStr` seems not working. And `fuctionB` always takes the previous `str`.

Through internet search, it seems to be the `useState` asynch issue, but tried various ways of suggested, none of them works in my case. Appreciate any help!

Comment: What you have in child component?
If is there any input and you want to set that input value in parent then you can directly run this function on input change.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing a common confusion among React developers. The problem is that state update are asynchronous - the updates on states are not reflected until the component rerenders.

This short [article](https://dev.to/shareef/react-usestate-hook-is-asynchronous-1hia) suggest a simple way to solve it.

Comment: I have tried the way described in the article you cited (using `useEffect`) but no luck. My case is different is that I have 2 callback functions and need the latest state there